# C#: How do i access file in eg. ProjectFolder/file.txt?

Tags: c#

i am new to c#. if i have a file in `ProjectFolder\file.txt`, how can i access it in code. eg. i want to read a file in code. i remember the path looks like `application://.../file.txt` but i cant remember how exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set your *Copy to Output Directory* property of your file to *Copy if newer*:

[image: Screenshot]

When you run your program from the output directory, you can simply open the file from the current directory:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("file1.txt");
```

Comment: be sure to add the folder to the path of the file if the file is in a project folder

Answer (score 1):

Most people's solutions refer to accessing a file on your file system.  However, you mentioned application local URIs, which made me think you are talking about embedded resources.  Those resources aren't a separate file on your filesystem.  So, the rest of my post is about that.

If you would like to include the file in your assembly, you have to change the properties on the file, changing the BuildAction property to Embedded Resource.

[image]

From there, you can access it with the resource path, as you described (see Pack URIs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx), or you can access it this way:

```
var stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetManifestResourceStream("ConsoleApplication1.blah.txt");
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
```